Elevated VS2022 creates folders with Admin owner instead of user account and causing problems for GIT
All the time I am running Visual Studio with elevated rights to access Windows 10 services and this works fine. However, once I clone new GIT repository the VS creates folders with wrong owner which results in various problems. For example trying to fetch using git command line shows fallowing error:
d:\_PROJECTS\Project1>git fetch
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'D:/_PROJECTS/Project1'
'D:/_PROJECTS/Project1' is owned by:
        'S-1-5-32-544'
but the current user is:
        'S-1-5-21-179508888-00000000005-000000000-000000'
To add an exception for this directory, call:
        git config --global --add safe.directory D:/_PROJECTS/Project1

Using TortoiseGIT does not show any branches at all and VS2022 always showing repository as disconnected. The problem can be fixed by simply changing owner and then inheriting change for all children folders.
With my older laptop I never had such a problem but now its gone and I can't find out differences with my new PC. How to fix this problem that elevated Windows 10 application running under user account creates folders with user's ownership instead of Administrator?
Environment: Windows 10 21H2 with ADO. My account is listed under administrators group (Local Users And Groups settings).

Reevaluate if you really need to run VS as administrator because it's been a very long time, i.e. many years, since I had to do it and it should be avoided.

With my older laptop I never had such a problem

Yes, it's a (relatively) new security protection where git try to detect files changed by another user.
The workaround is written in the error message. Launch the command:
git config --global --add safe.directory D:/_PROJECTS/Project1


I still need admin rights since I need to open ports and running service  requires admin account. Once we migrate to new NET8 and eliminate WCF dependency possibly it will be an option to run without admin rights. Will take a bit of time to do this.
The command does not work but I guess the reason that I have different credentials for these repositories in this folder and I need somehow to configure this difference.
